# Laravel: where I can override laravel code before response is returned?

Tags: php, laravel

I want override laravel at place where response is returned. Then I want to detect status code(200 or 301) and if request is ajax. If status code is 200 and request is ajax I want to return custom html. Something like
 :

```
protected function returnResponse($statusCode, $html, $redirectUrl){
    if($statusCode == 200  &&  isAjax()){
        return parent::returnResponse($customStatusCode, $customHtml, $customRedirectUrl);
    }
    return parent::returnResponse($statusCode, $html, $redirectUrl);
}
```

EDITED:
I have this:

```
class SomeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // do before 

        $request = $next($request);

        //do after

        return $request;
    }
}
```

But how to detect if current response is redirect ?

Comment: [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: do you have something more ?

Comment: In your question you said you want to return a custom response if the request is ajax. Why do you now need to know if the response is redirect?

Comment: because if response is redirect (301) and ajax, it is complicated and browser related "turn off" redirect follow in jquery, so when request is ajax and 301 I want to change 301 to 200 and then manualy redirect .

Comment: Ok see my answer below, I've walked through the pieces I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inspect the final response and possibly return an alternate response, let's write a simple middleware.

It sounds like you want to do your checks at the end, *after* the default response has been built (so you can examine it). So we'll start like this:

```
// First get the default response
$response = $next($request);
```

Our `$response` variable will now hold the response Laravel is about to respond with.

If you want to see if the response is a redirect, you can easily check for a `RedirectResponse` instance:

```
$isRedirect = $response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
```

You can test to see if the original request is ajax quite simply:

```
$isAjax = $request->ajax();
```

If you want to now return a different response instead of the one you were handed, I'd use the simple `response()` helper method:

```
return response($content, $status);
```

Putting it together, I believe this is roughly what you're looking for:

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class HijackMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if($request->ajax() && $response instanceof RedirectResponse) {
            return response("This is a <strong>different and custom</bold> response");
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is good, now I need to get redirected url and thats it.

Comment: @fico7489 `$response->getTargetUrl()`

Comment: @fico7489 I just rejected the edit. You already have the `$request` handed to your function, use that! Much better than calling the `\Request` facade.

Comment: @fico7489 if you prefer `$response->getStatusCode() == 301`, that's fine. I prefer looking for an instance `RedirectResponse`, I think it's clearer what the code is looking for. Your call.

Comment: @fico7489 Make sure you have that `use` statement at the top of your file to import that class. Also, just `dd($response)` to inspect it and see what it is!

Answer (score 1):

My final solution :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Response;
use Request;

class AjaxForm
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if(Request::ajax() && $response->status() == 301) {
            return (Response::make($response->getTargetUrl(), '200'));
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```